# Как заблокировать всё, кроме браузера?

Tags: delphi, windows, браузер

ОС: windows xp
Задача: Нужно написать браузер или использовать готовый, чтобы при входе в систему открывался только он, а всё остальное блокировалось (диспетчер задач, программы, рабочий стол и т.д.) Так же нужен доступ только к одному сайту. Без вкладок, каких-то настроек, сворачивания и т.п.

По сути делаем терминал-компьютер установленный в магазине.
Какие идеи?

Comment: Уточните, при чем тут Delphi?

Comment: Похожий вопрос с похожими условиями: http://serverfault.com/questions/18879/how-to-lock-down-windows-xp-for-use-as-an-internet-kiosk

Comment: Может стоит воспользоваться специализированным решением для этого? http://porteus-kiosk.org/

Answer (score 1):

Имеется ли реальная причина реализовывать это на именно на Win?
В *nix есть браузер epiphany. Там делается просто. Открывается нужный сайт, выбирается пункт "Создать приложение", готово. При запуске будет открываться этот сайт. Главное, что бы через этот сайт юзер не смог проникнуть на другой, тут уж либо с сайтом разбираться, либо делать зеркало. Возможно это частично решит вопрос. На *nix-ах можно сделать проще, запускать чистый X сервер, в котором в автозагрузе будет приложение из epiphany в полный экран. Даже если его умудрятся закрыть, сделать ничего толкового нельзя будет.
По Win возможно реализовать тот же механизм сходным путём. Сделать некое приложение в полный экран.

UPD не в курсе, как в винде приложения уходят в полный экран, у меня на Gnome просто F11.

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом